# Error after Creating S3 bucket with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I created an s3 bucket in terraform. However after creating this bucket, I am getting the error:
error getting S3 Bucket Object Lock configuration: AccessDenied: Access Denied

I am using AWS academy so I do not have many permissions, however, there is a role in AWS academy that allows the user to do stuff with s3. Is there a way to attach this IAM role to the S3 bucket so access it via Terraform?

I would like to upload images to this bucket, however I can no longer deploy code due to Terraform trying to access the Object Lock Configuration which it does not have access to. Is there a way to tell terraform to not try to not try to get this information?

Here is my code

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

[Image of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6y7.png)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are doing? What is your TF code?

Comment: I have added the code. It is just simply creating a bucket. My terraform code allows me to create the bucket initially, however anytime I write Terraform plan again, it displays the error mentioned above. Is there a way to specify Terraform to not access the bucket object lock configuration since I do not need that information?

Comment: Does your bucket exist ? Because the error is referred to the bucket object lock. Object Lock can help prevent objects from being deleted or overwritten for a fixed amount of time or indefinitely. Could you check the aws console ?

Comment: Yes, the bucket exists however I can no longer run terraform code after creating it because of this error. My next step is to upload images to this bucket, but I am being stopped due to the error always trying to access the Object Lock Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you have enable object lock to your bucket which prevents you to write or delete any files in your s3 bucket.

One way is to disable it from the console and refresh the state of terraform.

[image]

Comment: My Object lock is not enabled, however, terraform is trying to get-object-lock-configuration  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-lock-configuration.html

which apparently I do not have permission to do. Is there a way to tell terraform to ignore this variable since it will error out if it tries to retrieve it?

Comment: Coudl you try to delete your s3 and recreate it or you dont have permissions ?

Comment: I attached an image above. I have tried recreating my s3

Comment: Can you try create a second bucket and see if the object lock exist. I guess if this is true then the Academy put it for some reason and you cannot remove it...

Comment: Yes I never have permission to get object lock details. However I do not need them. Do you know of a way to bypass this and upload images to my bucket

Comment: Object lock prevent objects from being deleted or overwritten so you should be able to upload images.

Comment: Yes I should, however Terraform keeps trying to access this information which makes it error out.

Comment: i would start in a fresh workspace and deploy again my stack to see if the error still exist. I guess then it should be something with your permissions from Academy and they need to give you more control.